# Finding volume of a segment

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, geometry, regions

I'm still pretty new to *Mathematica*, so I would like to seek advice regarding a geometrical problem.

I am currently trying to define that as an extra condition in the Mathematica code below.

```
  reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 <= 1 {z, y, x}];
  Volume[reg, Assumptions -> a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
```

Any one has any idea how to incorporate it into the extra conditions in defining the implicit region?

Comment: What is the equation of the plane ....?

Comment: In this case, the equation of the plane (XZ) is y = 0 right? I would need to rotate this plane about the point X and use the rotated plane as a condition in evaluating the volume. Not sure how do I do that though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let you have a vector ${\bf p}$, which is perpendicular to the plane and an ellipsoid with axes $(a,b,c)$. The illustration (2D for simplicity):

[image]

Mathematica can calculate the numeric value of the clipped volume easily

```
Nvolume[p_, abc_] := Volume[RegionIntersection[
   ImplicitRegion[{x, y, z}.N[p] > 0, {x, y, z}], 
   Ellipsoid[N[abc] {1, 0, 0}, N[abc]]]]

p = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
abc = RandomReal[{1, 2}, 3];

Nvolume[p, abc]
(* 16.2584 *)
```

Mathematica cannot derive the general formula, but it isn't difficult to derive manually. Let us introduce new coordinates

$$
x' = x/a, \quad y' = y/b, \quad z' = z/c.
$$

In these coordinates the ellipsoid becomes the unit ball

[image]

The Jacobian of this transformation is $J=abc$. In the new coordinates the normalized perpendicular vector is

$$
{\bf n} = \frac{(ap_x,bp_y,cp_z)}{\sqrt{a^2p_x^2+b^2p_y^2+c^2p_z^2}}.
$$

Now it is simple to integrate the volume along the axis $\xi$ because the cross section is a circle

$$
V=abc\int_{-n_x}^1\pi(1-\xi^2)d\xi = \pi abc \left(\frac{2}{3} + n_x - \frac{n_x^3}{3}\right)
$$

```
volume[p_, abc_] := π Times @@ abc (2/3 + # - #^3/3) &@@ Normalize[abc p]

volume[p, abc]
(* 16.2584 *)
```

The result is the same.

---

*Update:* OP asks also about the area of the intersection. It is also an interesting question.

Mathematica region functionality is very powerful for numerical computations:

```
Narea[p_, abc_] := Area[RegionIntersection[ImplicitRegion[{x, y, z}.N[p] == 0, {x, y, z}], 
   Ellipsoid[N[abc] {1, 0, 0}, N[abc]]]]

Narea[p, abc]
(* 6.20243 *)
```

The analytic formula can be derived using the Dirac $\delta$-function
\begin{multline}
A = \int_\text{ellipse} \delta \left({\bf r}\cdot\frac{{\bf p}}{p}\right)d{\bf r} = abcp \int_\text{unit ball} \delta \left(x'ap_x+y'bp_y+z'cp_z\right)d{\bf r}' = \\
\frac{abcp}{\sqrt{a^2p_x^2+b^2p_y^2+c^2p_z^2}}\int_\text{unit ball} \delta \left({\bf r}'\cdot{\bf n}\right)d{\bf r}'.
\end{multline}
It is the cross section of the unit ball. Hence
\begin{equation}
A = \frac{\pi abcp (1-n_x^2)}{\sqrt{a^2p_x^2+b^2p_y^2+c^2p_z^2}}.
\end{equation}

```
area[p_, abc_] := π Times @@ abc (1 - #^2) & @@ Normalize[abc p] Norm[p]/Norm[abc p];

area[p, abc]
(* 6.20243 *)
```

Comment: this is beautiful method and exposition

Comment: Hi there @ybeltukov, thats a concise analytical method nicely complementing ubpdqn's proposed implementation! I understand that a plane takes `{x,y,z}.N[p] = 0`, but what does it mean when `{x, y, z}.N[p] > 0` ? Also, how could I get a rotation angle of the plane w.r.t horizontal using the normal vector `p`?

Comment: @Corse, `{x, y, z}.N[p] > 0` means the half of the space on the one side of the plane. As in ubpdqn's you can use `p = {Sin[a], 0, Cos[a]}`.

Comment: @ybeltukov thanks for the clarification, i realise that the value of 'a' has to be in terms of a negative angle to get the volume under the rotated plane. Sorry to bother, could there be a simple modification to the code to get the corresponding area of the intersecting plane through the ellipsoid?

Comment: @Corse, you can change the sign of `p` (e.g. `p = -{Sin[a], 0, Cos[a]}`) or change `> 0` to `< 0` in `Nvolume` and signs of `#` and `#^3` in `volume`

Comment: @ybeltukov oh i see, i didnt know that the implicitregion function could accept ==0, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ybeltukov pardon my ignorance, but how did you managed to set the pivot point of the plane at the left edge of the ellipse (in your first figure)? Does it have to do with the origin of the ellipsoid?

Comment: @Corse `N[abc] {1, 0, 0}` is the ellipsoid's center. It is the same as `N[{abc[[1]], 0, 0}]`, i.e. $(a,0,0)$.

Comment: @ybeltukov sorry to trouble you, is there a similar method of deriving the equation of the Area of the intersecting plane in the ellipsoid? e.g. something similar to the `volume[p_,abc_]` equation

Comment: @ybeltukov my advance apologies for bringing you back here again, may I know how could I derive an equation for **`area[p_, abc_]`** ? Could I simply add on the lines: **`an[a_] := {Cos[Pi/2 - a], Sin[Pi/2 - a], 0}`** and **`Refine[area[angle, {a, b, c}], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]`** ?

Comment: @ybeltukov if I do as such, there is a term **`Norm[angle]`** How should that be computed?

Comment: @Corse Sorry, I don't understand you. My answer has derivation of `area[p_, abc_]` and it takes `p` as a normal vector, not an angle.

Comment: @ybeltukov Apologies, I guess I didn't phrase my question properly. Actually what I would like to do is to derive an equation for the intersecting area between the plane and the ellipsoid. Previously ubpdqn has derived an equation for the volume based on your answer to this question. Do refer to this thread [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63608/equation-of-a-transformed-roatted-ellipsoid)

Comment: @ybeltukov thanks for your answers, they have been utmost helpful! By the way, can I arbitrarily define the position of the cutting plane by simply changing the coordinates of its normal `p`? such that the plane can cut anywhere on the ellipsoid

Comment: @Corse Yes, you can. It requires an additional point ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Point-normal_form_and_general_form_of_the_equation_of_a_plane)) and a corresponding code rewriting.

Answer (score 8):

**Visualization** of the @ybeltukov's answer

This is not an answer, just visualization of ybeltukov's answer.

Step 1 `direction3D` for direction handling.

```
opt1 = Sequence[Orange, Thick, Arrowheads[.15]];
opt2 = Sequence[PlotRange -> 1, Ticks -> None, Boxed -> False,
   ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 4}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}, 
   PlotRegion -> {{-.2, 1.05}, {-.2, 1.05}}, ImageSize -> 60];

direction3D[Dynamic[d_]] := DynamicModule[
  {$p = {0, π/2}, dd},
  LocatorPane[Dynamic[$p, ($p = #; dd @@ #) &],
   Graphics3D[
    {{opt1, Dynamic@Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, d}, .04]]},
     {Dynamic@Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, d/100}]}}, opt2
    ], {{-π, π}, {π, 0}},Appearance -> None, ImageMargins -> 0
   ], Initialization :> (d = {1, 0, 0};
  dd[t_, s_] := (d = {Sin[t] Sin[s], Cos[s], Cos[t] Sin[s]}))
  ]
```

Step 2 ybeltukov's result.

```
volume[p_, abc_] := π Times @@ abc (2/3 + # - #^3/3) & @@Normalize[abc p]
```

step3 visualization

```
opts = Sequence[Boxed -> False, Axes -> True,
   ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 4}, ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}];

Manipulate[
 elp = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.7], Orange, 
    Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}],
    Opacity[1], Black, 
    Text[Style[#, 16, Bold], #2] & @@@ {{"x", {3.1, 0, 0}}, {"y", {0,  2.2, 0}}, {"z", {0, 0, 2.2}}}
    }, opts];
 pln = ContourPlot3D[
   p.{x + a, y, z} == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
   Mesh -> None,
   ContourStyle -> {Opacity[.5], Darker@Green}];
 Show[elp, pln, Graphics3D[{
    Text[Style[
      StringJoin["V= ", ToString[N@volume[p, {a, b, c}]/Pi], "\[Pi]"],
       20], {2, 2, 0}]}]],
 Pane[Row[{
    Pane[direction3D[Dynamic[p]], ImageMargins -> {{0, 40}, {0, 0}}], 
    Pane[Column[{Control@{{a, 2}, 1, 2}, Control@{b, 1, 2}, 
       Control@{c, 1, 2}}]]}]]]
```

> [image]

Comment: thats a nice visualization! thank you

Answer (score 6):

Functions for generating ellipsoid $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$ and plane through point $\vec{p}$ with normal $\vec{n}$, i.e $\vec{n}\cdot(\vec{r}-\vec{p})=0$

```
el[a_, b_, c_, x_, y_, z_] := x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2
pl[n_, p_, x_, y_, z_] := z /. First@Solve[n.({x, y, z} - p) == 0, z]
```

Using as an example: a=1, b=2,c=3 and normal {1,0,par}:

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[
    Plot3D[Evaluate[pl[{1, 0, par}, {-1, 0, 0}, x, y, z]], {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
    RegionPlot3D[
     Evaluate[
      reg = (el[1, 2, 3, x, y, z] < 1 && 
         pl[{1, 0, par}, {-1, 0, 0}, x, y, z] > z)], {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
     Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Red, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"], 
    RegionPlot3D[
     Evaluate[el[1, 2, 3, x, y, z] < 0.9], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
      3}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.2]], 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Mesh -> None], 
    PlotRange -> Table[{-3, 3}, {3}], ImageSize -> 400],
   StringForm["Volume of red region:`1`", 
    NumberForm[RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y, z}]], 3]],
   StringForm["Volume of ellipsoid:`1`", NumberForm[N@4 Pi 1 2 3/3, 3]]
   }]
 , {par, 0.5, 4}]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

In relation to comment:

```
rot[a_, p_, x_, y_, z_] := pl[{Sin[a], 0, Cos[a]}, p, x, y, z]
```

This interactive graphic shows relation of normal to plane and what I understand is the desired angle from horizontal plane:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[RegionPlot3D[
   Evaluate[el[1, 2, 3, x, y, z] < 1], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4,
     4}, Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]], 
  Plot3D[rot[a Degree, {-1, 0, 0}, x, y, z], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
   Mesh -> False, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.5]}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Arrow[2 {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, {Red, 
     Arrow[2 {{0, 0, 0}, {Sin[a Degree], 0, Cos[a Degree]}}]
     },
    {Arrow[{{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]},
    {Arrow[{{-1, 0, 0}, {-1 + 2 Cos[a Degree], 0, -2 Sin[a Degree]}}]}
    }]], {a, 0, 90, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: hi there ubpdqn, thank you for the great implementation! Just wondering, how would I be able to obtain the volume of the red region in a generalized equation based on a specified rotation angle? I would still need to go through and fully understand your code there. I'm still not too clear as to how you managed to defined the plane (using vector product) and rotation axis.

Comment: @Corse see update in relation to angles

Comment: you have addressed my exact problem!! but I have a couple of queries I hope you could advise: 1) What is the term 'par' supposed to represent and how do I convert it to the rotation angle 'a' ? 2) When I completely set the value of 'par' to the extreme right, which gives a value of par=4, the corresponding volume of the red region is 11 which is less than half of the volume of ellipsoid. How do I edit par to obtain the correct limits? (i.e. volume for a horizontal and a vertical plane)

Comment: Also,  to edit the geometry of the ellipse, I would have to edit the values of a_,b_,c_ for each occurence in the el[] function right?

Comment: @Corse par just varies the normal vector that defines the plane (1,0,par). You could use the second or updated code `rot` to define the inclined plane and the relevant inequalities. Yes, I merely chose a=1,b=2,c=3 for illustrative purposes. You can choose what you like. Finally please also see my answer to your question re: rotation about arbitrary axis:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61782/1997

Comment: with regards to my 2nd question, i realise by changing the last line of your first code to {par, 0.01, 30}, I could get a volume of 12.4. This value doesn't increase anymore upon changing the upper limit of 'par'. Any ideas?

Comment: for the `rot[a_, p_, x_, y_, z_] := pl[{Sin[a], 0, Cos[a]}, p, x, y, z]`, am i supposed to use it to replace `pl[n_, p_, x_, y_, z_] := z /. First@Solve[n.({x, y, z} - p) == 0, z]`?  thank you in advance for being patient with me

Comment: @Corse as par gets large you approach the horizontal plane, if upper bound is 100, i get 12.5 and 1000, 12.6...the region measure depends on how well region is disretized. Other answers (and approaches) could provide analytical solution for these well defined regions.

Comment: @Corse with respect to `rot`, yes, this allows you to choose angle `a`. When a=0, normal vector is (0,0,1) hence horizontal plane, when a=Pi/6, normal is (1/2,0,Sqrt[3]/2), so plane will be rotated about y axis Pi/6 etc.

Comment: oh i see, so if `rot[a_, p_, x_, y_, z_] := pl[{Sin[a], 0, Cos[a]}, p, x, y, z]` is used, then it will be correct to use `rot[a Degree, {-1, 0, 0}, x, y, z]` to substitute the lines containing `pl[{1, 0, par}, {-1, 0, 0}, x, y, z]` in the 1st code you provided?