# Rotating a plane about an arbitrary axis

Tags: graphics3d, computational-geometry

I would like to rotate a plane by $k$ degrees about an arbitrary axis. How should I do it using `RotationTransform`?

---

hmm i realise if I do the following

```
F[x, y] := 0;
Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

I can define a plane as below, but how do I bound the extent of the plane? It seems to go on infinitely.

I tried something like this but it didnt work:

```
F[x, y] := 0 && -2 <= x <= 2 && -2 <= y <= 2
```

[image]

I then set up a function to perform the rotation about the y-axis through a point:

```
G[x, y] := RotationTransform[Pi/8, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}]
```

But strangely nothing appears. Anyone knows whats going on here?

Comment: What's the way you are describing this plane? parametric vector, etc.

Comment: I'm currently using a xz plane which should be described by y=0. how could i rotate it about an arbitrary point about the y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[#, 
      RotationTransform[
       angle Degree, {b, c, d}]] & /@ {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 
        0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, 
   InfiniteLine[{0, 0, 0}, {b, c, d}]}, 
  PlotRange -> Table[{-3, 3}, {3}]], {angle, 0, 360, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 Delimiter, 
 Style["Rotation Axis", Bold], {{b, 0, "axis x"}, 0, 
  1}, {{c, 0, "axis y"}, 0, 1}, {{d, 0.01, "axis z"}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For a starter

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Opacity[.3],
   Green, poly = Polygon[.5 {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}}],
   Polygon[.5 {{-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}}],
   Polygon[.5 {{0, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, -1}}],
   EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.7], 
   {Red, GeometricTransformation[poly, RotationTransform[t Pi/8, axis, {px, py, pz}]]},
   PointSize[.05], Opacity[1], Black, Sphere[{px, py, pz}, .05]},
   Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> 400, SphericalRegion -> True, Boxed -> False],
 {{axis, {1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0} -> "x", {0, 1, 0} -> "y", {0, 0, 1} -> "z"}},
 {{px, 0}, -1, 1}, {{py, 0}, -1, 1}, {{pz, 0}, -1,  1}, Delimiter,
 {{t, 0}, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

**Update:**

```
fX[x, y] := ConditionalExpression[0, -4 <= x <= 4 && -4 <= y <= 4];
Manipulate[plt1 = Show[Plot3D[fX[x, y], {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
    Evaluated -> True, Mesh -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], Blue], 
    PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}, {-6, 6}},
    Lighting -> "Neutral", ImageSize -> 400,
    SphericalRegion -> True, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", BoxRatios -> 1], 
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], Red, Sphere[{px, py, pz}, .2]}]];
 MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#,
    RotationTransform[t Pi/8, axis, {px, py, pz}]] &, plt1, {1}],
 {{axis, {1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0} -> "x", {0, 1, 0} -> "y", {0, 0, 1} -> "z"}},
 {{px, 0}, -1, 1}, {{py, 0}, -1, 1}, {{pz, 0}, -1, 1},
 Delimiter, {{t, 0}, -8, 8}]
```

[image]