# Equation of a transformed (rotated) ellipsoid

Tags: regions, geometry

Given an ellipsoid with semi-axis `{a,b,c}` and cantered at `{a,0,0}`, **how do I use [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html) to:**

1. Rotate the ellipsoid with respect to the y-axis
2. Obtain the volume bellow the plane $z=0$

Finally, I need to get a general equation to obtain the bounding region.

Comment: I am having trouble with trying to understand what you are asking. 1) you use left-handed coordinate system in your diagram. This in not consistent with _Mathematica_'s way of plotting with a right-handed coordinate system. 2) You ask about doing a *rotation* about the y-axis, but your diagram shows a *translation* along the x-axis. 3) you introduce a parameter `h` in you volume expression without explanation or defintion.

Comment: @m_goldberg I agree that it is difficult to understand exactly what is desired. In my answer, I referred to OP previous question,  a starting point as it seems similar...rotating plane through origin<->rotating ellipsoid around y axis but I may have misunderstood

Comment: I think the question is clear enough to have two answers, don't see reason to be closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be equivalent to your previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61754/finding-volume-of-a-segment/61810#61810).

ybeltukov's [beautiful answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/61810/1997) can be adapted. His answer provides volume above x-y plane.

```
volume[p_, abc_] := π Times @@ abc (2/3 + # - #^3/3) & @@ Normalize[abc p]
an[a_] := {Cos[Pi/2 - a], Sin[Pi/2 - a], 0}
vol[a_, abc_] := 4 Pi Times @@ abc/3 - volume[an[a], abc]
```

`a` in the above is the angle of rotation about the y axis through the origin. `vol` subtracts ybeltukov's answer from the volume of the ellipsoid.

Some 'reality checks':

Sphere, zero angle:`Refine[vol[0, {a, a, a}], {a > 0}]` yields volume of hemisphere: (2 $a^3 \pi$)/3

General ellipsoid, zero angle:

```
Refine[vol[0, {a, b, c}], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

yields: $2 \pi a b c /3$

General ellipoid 90 degree (counterclockwise) should be zero:

```
Refine[vol[Pi/2, {a, b, c}], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

and is.

General answer:

```
Refine[vol[angle, {a, b, c}], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

yields:

```
4/3 a b c π - 
  a b c π 
    (2/3 + 
     (a Sin[angle])/Sqrt[b^2 Abs[Cos[angle]]^2 + a^2 Abs[Sin[angle]]^2] - 
     (a^3 Sin[angle]^3)/(3 (b^2 Abs[Cos[angle]]^2 + a^2 Abs[Sin[angle]]^2)^(3/2)))
```

You may wish to simplify or refine further.

Apologies if I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: if the code is to be adapted to obtain the area of the ellipse lying on the xy plane, it would require a separate definition of the ellipse equation right? say using RegionMeasure?

Comment: I think the OP explicitly asked for the use of `RotationTransform`.

Comment: @rhermans thank you for your helpful answer. I accept my interpretation may be incorrect. However, I interpreted the primary aim of the question to determine a closed form expression for the volume of region of rotated ellipsoid that is below x-y plane (consistent with his previous question). His use of `RotationTransform` was to support this aim. In  my view, this unnecessarily complicates matters. It may well be the OP accepted my answer prematurely. However, that is a matter you and OP may wish to discuss.

Comment: @ubpdqn your implementation is a great solution! I'm just wondering (in my extremely limited knowledge of Mathematica) if `RotationTransform` would make it more straightforward to compute the intersection area and also the bounded volume. To be clear, your interpretation of my answer has been perfect! @rhermans Well I guess not, seems like my suggestion of using `RotationTransform` is causing more problems in obtaining the area and volume than I anticipated. Thank you for helping me understand how it works!

Comment: @Corse I made a small mistake an[a_]:={Cos[Pi/2-a],0,Sin[Pi/2-a]} as you are rotating ellipsoid about y axis. . There are many ways to get answers as this site is testimony to. So  have fun. It is 1:28 am in the antipodes and doing this from phone. Apologies for error but concept, courtesy of ybeltukov, sound.

Comment: @ubpdqn thanks for the clarification! I made the changes and seems like the solution for `Refine[vol[angle, {a, b, c}], {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]` is still the same. Truly, you have been a great help =)

Comment: @ubpdqn Sorry to post an additional enquiry on your implementation.  Instead of computing the volume, how could I obtain the equation for the area below the x-axis (i.e. 2D ellipse instead of 3D ellipsoid). I attempted the computation using your equation and tried to set dimension `b=0`. But that resulted in an error.

Answer (score 4):

To use [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html), as far as I know, you need to have either a vector (or parametric function) or a graphic primitives. I'm still trying to figure out how to transform regions defined by [`ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html)

### For vector

We define the ellipsoid parametrically by

```
paramE = {a + a Cos[u] Sin[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[v]}
```

and the rotation function

```
rf = RotationTransform[Pi/8, {0, 1, 0}]
```

That can be plot by

```
ParametricPlot3D[rf[paramE] /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 1}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### For graphic primitives

```
Graphics3D[
 GeometricTransformation[
  Ellipsoid[{2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 1}],
  RotationTransform[Pi/8, {0, 1, 0}]
  ]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### For regions

Here the function to use with `RotationTransform` is [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion.html)

```
rotEl = TransformedRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[x^2/4 + y^2 + z^2 < 1, {x, y, z}], 
  RotationTransform[Pi/8, {0, 1, 0}]];
```

Now we intersect with the half plane

```
cutEl = RegionIntersection[rotEl, ImplicitRegion[z < 0, {x, y, z}]]
```

For display

```
RegionPlot3D[cutEl, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### The equation

```
RotationTransform[w, {0, 1, 0}][{a + a Cos[u] Sin[v], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[v]}]
```

> ```
> {Cos[w] (a + a Cos[u] Sin[v]) + c Cos[v] Sin[w], b Sin[u] Sin[v], c Cos[v] Cos[w] - (a + a Cos[u] Sin[v]) Sin[w]}
> ```

Comment: yeah, it does seem like the parametric approach is somewhat unwieldy due to the transformation functions. I'll try to work on your implementation to get the volume. thank you!