# A triple integral involving Abs over an ellipsoidal region

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, regions

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to calculate a triple integral. But *Mathematica* doesn't output for half an hour and the CPU occupancy rate of my Wolfram doesn't changed when it's calculating.
Here is the code:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = Abs[x + y + z];
Integrate[f[x, y, z] Boole[x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2 <= 1], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},{z, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

I think it shouldn't spend a lot time to calculate this; I Googled and searched, but I still can't solve. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Is a numerical value okay? Try `NIntegrate` rather than `Integrate`. It will give you a number in half a second.

Comment: After a change of (ellipsoidal) coordinates, the integral becomes `Integrate[Abs[Cos[v] + 2 (Cos[u] + Sin[u]) Sin[v]] Sin[v], {u, 0, 2 π}, {v, 0, π}]/16`. At least in this case, *Mathematica* is faster in determining that it doesn't have a clue on how to deal with it symbolically. FWIW, the integral can be expressed using the new region functionality: `Integrate[Abs[x + y + z], {x, y, z} ∈ Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1/2}]]`.

Comment: You can transform the ellipsoid region to a unit ball, and align the norm of plane $x+y+z=0$ (should be something like $x+y+\zeta/2 = 0$ under new coord system) to the new $z$ axis, then you'll find yourself a very simple integral which can be symbolically done by Mathematica in seconds to get an exact answer $\frac{3 \pi }{8}$.

Comment: @Silvia How about giving an answer :) ?

Comment: Here's one way to do @Silvia's lovely approach: `tr = Composition[ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1/2}], RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1/2}}]]; Integrate[(Abs[x + y + z] /. Thread[{x, y, z} -> tr[{x, y, z}]]) Det[D[tr[{x, y, z}], {{x, y, z}}]], {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[]]`

Comment: @xzczd Actually I think this is more like a math question than a MMA one, so I didn't make it a formal answer. (I thought this question has been merged to Math.SE already..)

Comment: related: [Finding volume of a segment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61754/4678)

Answer (score 2):

This could be an option:

```
RegionPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + 4 z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question about `Integrate`?